# RadiusNetworks iBeacon library for android: calibration

Tags: android, ibeacon, calibration

I am using the RadiusNetworks library for measuring the distance to iBeacons. The official app from RadiusNetworks (iBeacon Locate) provides a calibration feature to improve accuracy.

How do I perform a calibration when using the library as part of my application?

Thanks & Best
ben

Comment: The calibration isn't performed on the receiver but on the emitter. It corresponds to the mean rssi you receive while at a 1m distance of the emitter. This value is the last of the 4 data sent by an iBeacon UUID + major + minor + 1B calibration data

Comment: but the measured rssi would be different for each kind of device (e.g. depending where the bluetooth antenna is attached). Or are all mobile devices calibrated such that the would read the same rssi for a given iBeacon?

Comment: rssi DOES depend on where the bluetooth antenna is attached. Distance measurement is far from being reliable with iBeacon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calibration function in the [BeaconScope](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davidgyoungtech.beaconscanner&hl=en_US&gl=US) app will give you a number to be configured into a hardware beacon to make distance estimates as accurate as possible.  Once set, the beacon transmitter will emit this value to receiving devices (both Android or iOS).  Because it is transmitted over the air, there is no need to manually configure the [Android iBeacon Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/) with the value.  The library will read it out of the beacon transmission.

For this to work, you need to configure the calibration power value into your beacon.  How you do this depends on the type of beacon you are using.  Most beacon vendors allow this, but each product has a different procedure.  For my company's RadBeacon products, for example, we have iOS and Mac apps to set this value over the air.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to estimate the accurate distance using RSSI of the iBeacon.

You have to use [log distance path loss model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-distance_path_loss_model)(shortly, LDPL) to change RSSI to distance.

In LDPL, you need below two parameters, simply.

- Initial RSSI
- Path loss exponent

And I recommend you [BeaconBox for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nemustech.beaconbox).

You can get these two parameters using this app.

Also, you can get Java source code for changing RSSI to distance.

I hope that you achieve the goal!